# As parameter , how to find which class invoke the current method

Tags: java

following situation in java

say in current class there is a method call returnStr , and this method will return a String , and this method may be invoke as a paramter in other class , so is there any way help me to find out which class invokes this method ?

```
 public class MyClass {
    public String returnStr() {
        // System.out.println("which class invokes me @_@")

        return "ABC";
    }
}

class D {
    public void printStr(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

class B {
    public void printStr(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

class C {
    public void printStr(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        a.printStr(myClass.returnStr());
        b.printStr(myClass.returnStr());
        c.printStr(myClass.returnStr());
        }
    }
```

as above code , is there a way help me to print A , B , C these three class name ? I tried to get the StackTrace array , but I just could get the name "Test" which invoked returnStr().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the Class A ?? This one will throw an error !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea. They have such function.

[image]

Comment: They cannot possibly have such function, because `A`, `B` and `C` do not do the calling here.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely, positively, no way of doing what you want, even after you fix your copy/paste error <sup>*</sup>: it is the `Test` class that does all invocations here; it *passes* the results that it gets from `myClass` to `A`, `B`, and `C`, which are *not* on the stack at the time the call to `MyClass` is made.

Arguably, there should be no reason for a method to find its callers: generally, methods (and functions in procedural languages) provide the level of abstraction intended to hide the logic from the caller, and insulate the caller from the logic (unless he chooses to "announce" itself through *parameters*).

This should lead you to a solution: since the method cannot find out to whom its output will be routed, the caller should pass this information in the parameter, like this:

```
public String returnStr(String whosCallingMe) {
    System.out.println(whosCallingMe);
    return "ABC";
}
```

Now call the method like this:

```
a.printStr(myClass.returnStr("A"));
b.printStr(myClass.returnStr("B"));
c.printStr(myClass.returnStr("C"));
```

---

<sup>*</sup> All three calls go to object of type `A`, because you forgot to replace `a.printStr` with `b.printStr` and `c.printStr` in the code that you copy/pasted.

Comment: thank you for your "no way" solution ^_^  . I won't take time on this , thank you so much.

Comment: @Kane.Sun You are welcome! If this answers your question and you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This will let other site visitors know that your problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ways to do this:

- Pass the callee for this particular class via a `ThreadLocal`. The downside is that it's a single-thread solution.
- Pass the callee as a parameter to a method. This way is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Pass the instance of the class to the returnStr() to get the class from where the method is called. All the below files lie under the same package.

**ParameterInstance .java**

```
public class ParameterInstance {
    public String returnStr(Object obj) {
        // System.out.println("which class invokes me @_@")
        System.out.println("Class is :: " + obj.getClass());
        return "ABC";
    }
}


class A {
    public void printStr(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}


class D {
    public void printStr(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

class B {
    public void printStr(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

class C {
    public void printStr(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ParameterInstance myClass = new ParameterInstance();
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        a.printStr(myClass.returnStr(a));
        b.printStr(myClass.returnStr(b));
        c.printStr(myClass.returnStr(c));
    }
}
```